# Add Release/ Release all Actions Acumatica mobile framework

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Good morning,

Im asking for your help, to advice me how to put a "Release or Release all" action in the mobile application.

I already added this Actions container (Screen AP503000 -Prepare Payments)

```
<s: complexType name = "Actions">
<s: sequence>
<s: element minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs = "1" name = "Cancel" type = "tns: Action" />
<s: element minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs = "1" name = "Process" type = "tns: Action" />
<s: element minOccurs = "0" maxOccurs = "1" name = "ProcessAll" type = "tns: Action" />
```

In the customization project/Mobile Application (Add Screen) I add this code:

add screen AP503000 {

```
add container "Actions" {
  add field "Cancel"
  add field "Process"
  add field "ProcessAll"
}

add container "Selection"{
  add field "PaymentMethod"
  add field "CashAccount"
  add field "PaymentDate"
  add field "Currency"
  add field "Vendor"
     
}
add container "DocumentsToPay"{
  add field "Selected"
  add field "DocumentType"
  add field "ReferenceNbr"
  add field "VendorID"
  add field "VendorName"
  add field "AmountPaid"
}
```

}

Attached the result in mobile device**
[Selection Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spam1.png)
[DocumentsToPay Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEw5R.png)

The actions does not show in the mobile interface,any advices/ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
add screen AP503000 {
add container "Selection"{
fieldsToShow = 5
listActionsToExpand = 1
containerActionsToExpand = 1
add field "PaymentMethod"
add field "CashAccount"
add field "PaymentDate"
add field "Currency"
add field "Vendor"
}

add container "DocumentsToPay" {    
add field "DocumentType"
add field "ReferenceNbr"
add field "VendorID"
add field "VendorName"
add field "Description"
add field "Account"
add field "DueDate"
add field "Balance"
add listAction "Process" {
  behavior = Void
  syncLongOperation = True
}    
add containerAction "EditDetail" {
  behavior = Open
  redirect = True
}
attachments {
}
```

}
}